# My GCDAsyncUdpSocket project gives me a warning

Tags: ios, objective-c

[My project and the warning message

Sorry, but I'm not allowed to send my picture of the project...so ...
The Project is like this:

ProjectName

UDP (Dir)

```
GCDAsyncUDPSocket.h

GCDAsyncUDPSocket.m
```

ProjectName (Dir)

```
ViewController.h

ViewController.m
```

1. This line in my ViewController:

   ```
   udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
   ```

gives me this warning:

> ***Sending 'ViewController *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id _Nullable'***

I have tried this in ViewController.h :

@interface ViewController : UIViewController '<'GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate'>'

( Without the apostrophes...)

I hope someone can help me.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your `delegate` as conforming to the protocol `GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate`.

In your `ViewController.m` you will have something like:

```
@interface ViewController () <GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate>
```

Also try dereferce selflike this:

```
__weak __typeof(self) weakself = self;
udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:weakself delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! But can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: I tried, but got an error:  Sending 'ViewController *__weak' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate>

Comment: Sorry, 'cause you were right in your first comment!  I tried to implement: @interface ViewController () <GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate> in the 'h' file, not the 'm' file! Sorry for my mistake! Thank you very much for your help!